# How to disable Oracle XE component which is listening on 8080?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

After installing Oracle XE, something in Oracle is listening on port 8080. I am not sure if they have an Apache HTTPD, a Tomcat, or something else. But how can I disable it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is Oracle XML DB HTTP Server; disable it as follows:

```
sqlplus '/ as sysdba'
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(0);
commit;
```

You might have to restart Oracle XE (not just the listener).

Comment: Then you need to restart Oracle XE related services, not sure which one.

Comment: In my case the port was closed after running that command. No need to restart here.